# Arduino and C++ changing port

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to do a GUI application using Qt but, for a reason I ignore, only one command arrive to the arduino card, the next ones don't arrive. And when I'm trying to reconnect the card, it doesn't allow me to do so. So I have two issues, the first one is changing the port of the Arduino card, in case it's not the same card, and the second one is succeed to send more than only one command to the arduino card without restarting each time the program.

The main code is

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "envoie.h"
#include "batterie.h"
#include "SerialClass.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int niveau_de_decharge = 80;
string entree;
bool marche_programme;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    brancherButton = new QPushButton(tr("Brancher"));
    brancherButton->show();
    debrancherButton = new QPushButton(tr("Débrancher"));
    debrancherButton->show();
    connectButton = new QPushButton(tr("Connexion"));
    connectButton->show();
    disconnectButton = new QPushButton(tr("Déconnexion"));
    disconnectButton->show();
    testButton = new QPushButton(tr("Test de la connexion"));
    testButton->show();
    pourcentagebatterieBar = new QProgressBar;
    retourText = new QTextBlock;
    valeurdefautSlider = new QSlider;
    connect(brancherButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::brancher);
    connect(connectButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::connexion);
    connect(debrancherButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::debrancher);
    connect(disconnectButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::deconnexion);
    connect(testButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::test);
    QVBoxLayout *buttonLayout1 = new QVBoxLayout;
        buttonLayout1->addWidget(brancherButton, Qt::AlignTop);
        buttonLayout1->addWidget(debrancherButton);
        buttonLayout1->addWidget(connectButton);
        buttonLayout1->addWidget(disconnectButton);
        buttonLayout1->addWidget(testButton);
        buttonLayout1->addStretch();
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
           // mainLayout->addWidget(retourText, 0, 0, Qt::AlignTop); // ne marche pas actuellement
            mainLayout->addWidget(valeurdefautSlider, 0, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
            mainLayout->addWidget(pourcentagebatterieBar, 1, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
            mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout1, 1, 2);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setWindowTitle("TIPE Protection des batteries");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

std::wstring s2wsbis(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

std::wstring stempbis = s2wsbis("\\\\.\\COM3");
LPCWSTR portbis = stempbis.c_str();

Serial SPbis = Serial(portbis);

auto donnee(){
    cout << "Taper la commande a effectuer : " << endl;
    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [] {    //début de bout de programme qui fait quelque chose d'un peu magique
            auto s = ""s;
            if (std::cin >> s) return s;
            });                                 //fin de l'incompréhension
    while(f.wait_for(30s) != std::future_status::ready) {
        if (batterie()>=niveau_de_decharge){
            cout << "Batterie chargee" << endl;
            if(SPbis.IsConnected()){
                envoie("debrancher", SPbis);
            }
            else {
                cout << "Veuillez connecter la carte arduino ou relancer le programme" << endl;
            }
            cout << "Taper la commande a effectuer : " << endl;
        }
    }
       entree = f.get();

        if (entree=="change"){
            cout << "Changement de la valeur de la variable decharge_defaut" << endl << "Valeur actuelle : " << niveau_de_decharge << endl;
            cout << "Nouvelle valeur : ";
            cin >> niveau_de_decharge;
            cout << "Valeur changee : " << niveau_de_decharge << "% est le nouveau seuil de charge maximal" << endl;
        }
        else if (entree=="batterie") {
            cout << "Le niveau de batterie est de " << batterie() << "%." <<endl;
            if (branchement()==1){
                cout << "L'ordinateur est branche" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Ordinateur sur batterie" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (entree=="close"){
                marche_programme=false;
        }
        else if (entree=="help") {
            cout << "   Liste des commandes : " << endl
                        << "        connect" << endl
                        << "        close" << endl
                        << "        change" << endl
                        << "        batterie" << endl
                        << "        brancher" << endl
                        << "        changeport" << endl;
        }
        else {
            envoie(entree, SPbis);
        }
    return 0;
}

void MainWindow::test() {
    if(SPbis.IsConnected()){
        cout << "Arduino connectée" << endl;
    }
    else {
     cout << "Erreur";
    }
}

void MainWindow::brancher() {
    envoie("brancher", SPbis);
};

void MainWindow::debrancher() {
    envoie("debrancher", SPbis);
};

void MainWindow::pourcentagebatterie() {
    batterie();
};

void MainWindow::connexion(){
    cout << "Tentative de connexion sur le port " << portbis << "..." << endl;
    Serial SPbis=Serial(portbis);
    Sleep(500);
    if(SPbis.IsConnected()){
        cout<<"Connexion etablie"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Impossible de se connecter" << endl;
    }
}
```

and I use the https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows/
to communicate between the arduino and the computer

EDIT

I modified the code which is sending the commands and retrieving the
arduino informations and when I send a new command, the Arduino card does not send any information back, so, despite the "true" in the connection test, the informations doesn't go in the opened port

Comment: Not sure but you create a global object `Serial SPbis = Serial(portbis);`. Then in `void MainWindow::connexion()` you create another one. My guess is only one object can access the port at a time.

Comment: Yes I know but despite I comment this line, the program stills not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed to resolve the "only one command uploading" by implementing it in my function envoie() here

```
#include "envoie.h"
#include <string>
#include "SerialClass.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned int MAX_DATA_LENGTH=255;
//char previousoutput[255];
char output[255];
char incomingData[255];
char prevoutput[255];

std::wstring s2ws3(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}




std::wstring stemp9 = s2ws3("\\\\.\\COM9");
LPCWSTR port9 = stemp9.c_str();
Serial SP = Serial(port9);

bool envoie(string data)
{
        cout << "Tentative d'envoie de la commande '" << data << "'" << endl;
        if (SP.IsConnected()) {
            char* charArray = new char[data.size() + 1];

            copy(data.begin(), data.end(), charArray);
            charArray[data.size()] = '\0';                  //stopsign for compliler


            SP.WriteData(charArray, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

            Sleep(ARDUINO_WAIT_TIME);

            SP.ReadData(output, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
            cout << "Retour de la carte : " << output << endl;
            std::fill_n(output,255,0);
           /* if (strcmp(prevoutput,output)==0){      //ne marche pas
                cout << "Retour identiques" << endl;
            }*/
            SP.ReadData(prevoutput, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);
            cout << charArray << " envoye avec succes" << endl;
            delete[] charArray;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Arduino deconnecte" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

By reopening each times the connection between the card and the computer

EDIT

Added a connection and deconnection button in order to change ports that works only by replacing the

```
Serial SP = new Serial(port9);
SP.IsConnected();
```

by

```
Serial* SP = new Serial(port9);
SP->IsConnected();
```

Hope this would help someone

Comment: If someone has a more optimized version, post it here